# Problems with Jquery Cookie and SlideToggle or Hide

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

I have visited many pages on stackoverflow about Jquery cookies, and i think i've found a suitable solution to what i wanna do. But i get this error, i just can't figure out. Hope you guys can help me.

```
index.html:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: signupcookie is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<!--Container for newsletter signup-->
<div id="signupToggled">


<div class="signupToggledContent">

  <h4>
    Tilmeld dig vores nyhedsbrev og vind et gavekort på 500 kroner.
  </h4>
  <p>
    Hver måned trækker vi lod om et gavekort på 500kr., blandt alle læsere af vores nyhedsbrev.
  </p>

</div>


<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="//mopra.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6ee93f66b0feabf294d03411a&amp;id=0888632a82"
  method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"
  name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <div class="group">
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" required>
          <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Tilmeld" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
        <input type="text" name="b_6ee93f66b0feabf294d03411a_0888632a82" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>

</div>

<!--HERE THE COOKIE WILL BE SET - Also it is here where the error comes up-->
<div id="signupToggle" value="Vind et gavekort!" onclick="signupcookie()"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">


$( document ).ready(function() {

  function signupcookie(){

     days=30;
     myDate = new Date();
     myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));

     document.cookie = 'signupcookie=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();

  }

  function CheckCookies(){
      if ($.cookie("signupcookie") === "Accepted")
      {
          $("#signupToggled").slideToggle();
      }
  }


  $( "#signupToggle" ).click(function(e) { 
    $( "#signupToggled" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {  });
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active'); 
  });


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For old-school event handling via onclick attribute, the function must exist already at the time this HTML element occurs. But since you are using jQuery here already, you should not be using onclick in the first place, but jQuery’s way of binding event handlers. (Which you are already doing, `$( "#signupToggle" ).click(...`)` - so add what your `signupcookie` does (or call it) there.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. :) 
Could you please elaborate on your solution? 
I've just startet to learn Jquery. :)

Comment: Remove the onclick attribute from the element - you already have a click handler for it, that you are setting up with `$( "#signupToggle" ).click(...)`. Inside the function that you pass to the click method here, either call `signupcookie()`, or put the code from that function into that place directly.